# Exception in Tkinter callback Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

i tried to make and code

it's about a coding for a prog to use camera in sign language so it's to window and the button to call the new window and open the camera but there is an error
and i don't know what part it can be the error in
so can you tell me

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np
import pkg_resources.py2_warn
import cv2
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk,Image 

def camera():
    global last_frame                                      #
    last_frame = np.zeros((480, 640, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    global cap
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    def show_vid():                                        
        if not cap.isOpened():
            print("cant open the camera")
        flag, frame = cap.read()
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        if flag is None:
            print ("Major error!")
        elif flag:
            global last_frame
            last_frame = frame.copy()

        pic = cv2.cvtColor(last_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)     
        img = Image.fromarray(pic)
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        lmain.imgtk = imgtk
        lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
        lmain.after(10, show_vid)
    window2=tk.Tk()
    window2.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
    window2.title("Show Your Hand Niga")
    lmain = tk.Label(master=window2)
    lmain.grid(column=0, rowspan=4, padx=5, pady=5)
    show_vid()
    window2.mainloop()                                  
    cap.release()
window= Tk()
window.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
window.title("Sign Language Eg V1.0")
Title =Label(window, text=("We are  here to help you connect with others "), font=("Arial Bold", 24 ))
Title.grid(column=0, row=0)
def image(smp):
    img = tk.PhotoImage(file="blue.png")
    img = img.subsample(smp, smp)
    return img
img4 = image(2)    
camera_btn =tk.Button(window, text="Open Camera ",compound=tk.CENTER,borderwidth=0, command=camera)
camera_btn.config(image=img4,font=('Arial Bold', 12))
camera_btn.grid(column=0, row=2)
im=Image.open("im2.png") 
photo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(im) 
image = Label(image= photo)
image.grid(column=0, row=1)
window.geometry=('720x490')
#finish 
window.mainloop()
```

when i run to open the camera it says

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "F:/New folder/New folder (2)/test/trygui2.py", line 37, in camera
    show_vid()
  File "F:/New folder/New folder (2)/test/trygui2.py", line 30, in show_vid
    lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1485, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1476, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1600" doesn't exist
```

thanks for your help

Comment: what is `lmain` and `lmain.imgtk` here

Comment: It is because you have used multiple instances of `Tk()`.